# form data not saving and not update image files and filed name in multiple tables

Tags: cakephp

in this editdrprofile.ctp file not retrieves gender field value and when am click save Drprofile link in editprofile page no action donne page refreshing no image uploaded nothing changed

**app/Controller/DashboardsController.php**

```
 public function index() {
 $this-> loadModel('Drprofile');
  $this->set('variable', $this->Drprofile->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Drprofile.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')))));
}

public function editdrprofile($id = null) {
          $this-> loadModel('Drprofile');

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Drprofile->findByuser_id($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is(array('Drprofile', 'put'))) {
        $this->Drprofile->user_id = $id;


    //  $this->set('posts', $this->carrier->find('all'));
        if($this->request->is('post')){
             Configure::read();
     //   pr($this->data); 
            $this->Carrier->create();
            $filename = null;

if (
    !empty($this->request->data['Drprofile']['image']['tmp_name'])
    && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Drprofile']['image']['tmp_name'])
) {
    // Strip path information
    $filename = basename($this->request->data['Drprofile']['image']['name']); 
    move_uploaded_file(
        $this->data['Drprofile']['image']['tmp_name'],
        WWW_ROOT . DS . 'documents' . DS . $filename
    );
    //$this->data['Carrier']['Resume'] = $filename;
}

//pr($filename);
// Set the file-name only to save in the database
$this->request->data['Drprofile']['image'] = $filename;
pr($this->data);
if ($this->Drprofile->save($this->request->data)) {
   // ...
     /*if ($this->Carrier->save($this->request->data)) {
                 if ($this->Carrier->save($this->data)) {
                 */
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Details has been saved.'));
                 return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Details'));
            }
            }


        /*pr_('$this->Drprofile->user_id = $id');
        if ($this->Drprofile->save($this->request->data)) {
            //$this->Drprofile->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));


            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));*/

    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }


    }
```

in model
**app/model/Drprofile.php**

```
<?php class Drprofile extends AppModel {

 var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}
?>
```

in **view/dashboards/index.ctp**

```
<?php 
 foreach ($variable as $post1):
 ?>

<table>

<tr><h3>Doctor Profile</h3></tr>
<tr> <td>TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT</td> <td><table>

<tr><td>Name</td><td><?php echo $post1['User']['fullname'];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td><td><?php echo $post1['User']['email'];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile</td><td><?php echo $post1['User']['contactnumber'];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><?php echo $post1['User']['gender'];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>D.O.b</td><td><?php echo $post1['Drprofile']['dob'];?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Experience</td><td><?php echo $post1['Drprofile']['exp'];?></td></tr>


</table></td></tr>


</table>
<?php

                echo $this->Html->link(
                    'Edit Profile', array('action' => 'editdrprofile', $post1['Drprofile']['user_id'])
                );
            ?> 
 <?php 

   endforeach; ?>
```

**app/view/editdrprofile.ctp**

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Drprofile');
?>

<table>
<tr><h3>Edit profile</h3></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('User.fullname'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('User.email'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mobile</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('User.contactnumber'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><?php 
$options=array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female');
$attributes=array('legend'=>false);
echo $this->Form->radio('User.gender',$options,$attributes);
?></td></td></tr>
<tr><td>D.O.b</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->text('dob'); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Experience</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->select('exp', array('options' => array('1 year','2 years ','3 years','4 years','5-10 years'))); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('drprofile.Resume', array('between'=>'<br />','type'=>'file'));?></td></tr>



<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Drprofile');?></td></tr>
<?php /*?><?php echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));?><?php */?>



</table>
```

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going on in your controller, you should place some logic in model or consider using some custom behaviours to store images like [Uploader](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader).

Comment: @skywalker when i clicked `<tr><td><?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Drprofile');?></td></tr>` no action done only page refreshing

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are doing this in Dashboards controller, and you are creating data for Drprofile. If you in the end you want to do it in DashboardsController then you should change your from to this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Drprofile', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'editdrprofile')
));
```

This way you are telling form what action to use. But I would suggest you move that to DprofilesController and edit that data there.

One more thing, you closed your form there and you place `$this->Form->input` for id after it, change that.